# MySQL join query trouble

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
user(uid(pk),username), swipe(swipeId(pk), user_uid(fk), hasSwipedUid)
```

The query

```
select * from user 
left join swipe on swipe.user_userId = user.userId
where hasSwiped_userId = 1 
 or hasSwiped_userId is null
```

This query returns the desired result BUT when a users swipe is no longer NULL it wont appear in the list since that user has swiped somebody else than uid 1.

I want all users that has not swiped me yet, or all users that has swiped me or users that hasnt swiped anyone. The problem is if e.g user 2 has swiped a user 10 and then user 1 (which would be ur device in this case) the row with 2 and 10 would appear and not the one with 1.

```
 uid, username, user_uId, hasSwiped_userId
4   A   4   1
2   B   2   1
3   D   3   9   <---- here we assume that uid 3 swiped uid 9 before uid 1 and therefore it shows up instead of 1 which is me(the user)
5   E   5   NULL
```

Comment: Please, switch to LEFT OUTER JOIN! Most people find that hard enough to understand... (Consider `main table left join optional data`, instead of `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: Do you really need a `WHERE` clause? Because based on your combination of `OR` conditions, you're covering every possible scenario, assuming `hasSwipeUid` is part of `swipe`.

Comment: no not really, but the problem is that if a user A has swiped user C before me(B) and then user A swipes B(me) the returning row from user A with hasSwipedUid will be C instead of B. I need it to be B.

Comment: @brondy Can you post some sample data and a desired result? That would be less ambiguous (less room for misinterpretation) and a visual representation is always helpful!

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Radu: added a desired result with explanation

Comment: Write separate queries for each condition, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: "I want all users that has not swiped me yet, or all users that has swiped me or users that hasnt swiped anyone." These sound like 3 entirely separate queries.

Comment: im not even sure if I have the right structure in the DB

Comment: Pls provide sample source data and expected results based on that sample data. It is pretty difficult to understand what you are after.

Comment: I updated the OP with a query that does return the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Your query selects all users in the **user** table that has an entry in the **swipe** table because there are **where** clauses on all possible values of **hasSwipedUid** , which are : **1, !1 or null**. Assuming that the swipe table holds entries for everytime a user swipes another user, the query lists all users who have ever swiped atleast once.

You might be getting rows with **2** and **10** but not with **1** because both **2** and **10** has swiped atleast once but **1** has not swiped anyone yet.

I think your query should be :

```
select distinct * from user inner join swipe on user.uid = swipe.user_uid
and (hasSwipedUid = 1 or hasSwipedUid = null)
```